# Vowel counter using 2 arguments

Tags: python, recursion, counter

I must create two functions, one that asks user for a character and determines whether a character is a vowel or isn't by returning true or false.

The second is to call the first function and ask the user to input a word.

This is what I have so far:

```
vowel = ["A","E","I","O","U","a","e","i","o","u"]
vowelinpt = input("Please enter a character: ")
def isVowel(x):
    if x in vowel:
        return True
    else: 
        return False

a = isVowel(vowelinpt)
print(a)

def countvowel(b):
    count = 0
    for a in b:
        if isVowel(a) == True
        count +=1
    return count

x = input("Please input a WORD: ")
y = countvowel(x)
print(y)
```

Any ideas on how to actually make it count the correct number of vowels?

Comment: Why are you asking user for a character? You have already asked him/her for a word.

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem? Are you getting an error? Are you getting output that doesn't look like what you expect?

Comment: Your code is sloppy, and wouldn't even run as you typed it out.  If you want people to take the time to help you, you need to do the same.  As it stands currently, the syntax for your second IF statement is wrong.  Your indentation was all over the place.  The use of input gives you an error.  Looking at the documentation for input shows that in this case you should use `raw_input()` instead of just `input()`.  The python interpreter would have told you this, and you could have fixed it.

Comment: @Rejected - Easy buddy.  I agree his formatting is poor, but there is no need to kill him for it.  Also, he is clearly using Python 3.x, which means it is right to use `input`.

Comment: the task was to ask for a character, then ask for a word. That's what i was instructed to do

Comment: I apologise, was just a little frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good (except the wrong indentation which I think is a copy-paste error). Just some minor items.

If you have

```
if somethingBoolean: return True
else: return False
```

you can simply write

```
return somethingBoolean
```

Hence:

```
def isVowel(x): return x in vowels
```

Now for counting, you just got the indentation wrong:

```
def countvowel(b):
    count = 0
    for a in b:
        if isVowel(a): count += 1
    return count
```

I hope this does the trick.

Comment: EXCELLENT! Thanks ever so much I was sooo close kinda.. haha

Answer (score 1):

Your `countvowel` function is pretty messed up. `count 0` isn't valid syntax, and your indentation is wrong. I think your main problem is that your `return` statement is inside the loop. When Python executes a `return`, the function stops right there and returns the value. It doesn't keep executing the function. Move the `return` out of the loop if it's inside.

Comment: I see, yes the return statement seemed to be the big issue. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with `countvowel` is that the indentation is messed up and you are missing a ":" after the if-statement.  This will fix it:

```
def countvowel(b):
    count = 0
    for a in b:
        if isVowel(a) == True:
            count +=1
    return count
```

However, you can really simplify this whole thing like so:

```
vowels = "aeiou"
vowelinpt = input("Please enter a character: ")
def isVowel(x):
   return x.lower() in vowels
a = isVowel(vowelinpt)
print(a)

def countvowel(b):
    # You can also do "return sum(a in vowels for a in b.lower())"
    return len(list(filter(isVowel, b.lower())))
x = input("Please input a WORD: ")
y = countvowel(x)
print(y)
```